# How do I access a Delphi function/procedure from C code in Linux platform

Tags: c, delphi

I have a code in C which is trying to access functions/procedure from Delphi units. I am compiling the Delphi code for Linux(CentOs) platform(using RAD studio) and I am getting 'Undefined reference' error for the functions whose definitions are in a .pas file and which is invoked from C code. Below are the steps I did in my test project

I have searched in google about how to access the Delphi functions from C programs, but I didnt get much help(apart from some suggestion like to use cdecl, extern etc.. which I have already done in my project). It would be great if I can get some help on resolving the 'Undefined reference' error in my below scenario.

1. Create a C program like below and save it as test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

extern void print(); //This function/procedure is defined in Delphi .pas files

void show()
{
  print();
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

2. Compile the C program using gcc to create .o file
    `gcc -c test.c -o test.o`
3. Create an archive file(.a file) containing the .o file like below
    `ar r test.a test.o`
4. In the Delphi code(Test.pas) Link the test.a file using $LINK and call the show() function defined in C. Show() function internally calls the print() function/procedure defined in Delphi unit Unit1.pas

```
    program TestProj;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas';

  {$LINK test.a}

  procedure show; cdecl; external 'test.a'

var
  res : integer;

  begin
  try
    show;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

5. The Unit1.pas included in the above Delphi code has the definition of print()

```
unit Unit1;

interface
procedure print; cdecl;

implementation
procedure print() cdecl;
begin
  writeln('Test Message');
end;
end.
```

6. Now when I compile the Delphi code (Test.pas), I am getting below 'undefined reference' error

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Users\testuser1\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Linux64\Debug\test.a(test.o):test.c:function show: error: undefined reference to 'print'
```

Comment: Isn't `test.a` self-contained, as in: how should it know it can later access `print()`? Are you sure you don't want to [export](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Writing_Dynamically_Loaded_Libraries) `print()` anywhere? Let alone using the most common ways: libraries?

Comment: Not sure if that's possible; and even if it is, since `print()` is inside `Unit1`, it would be exported as `Unit1_print` or something like that. Consider passing a function pointer instead.

Comment: @AmigoJack Thanks for the reply. From the link mentioned in your comment, it seems like the code that uses the 'export' should be a library. In my case, the code is a Delphi module which is not a library. Also I see in windows(which uses bcc32 C compiler) the code is using 'pascal' keyword for the C functions. For example, in my above code for show() function in C, the windows is having the signature like 'void pascal show()'. But in Linux(using gcc compiler), the keyword pascal is not available.

Comment: `exports` is not bound to your module type (`unit` versus `library` versus `program`) and can be used in any of those. Yes: not only DLLs but also EXEs can export functions - it's just that almost nobody does so and/or uses it this way.

Comment: @AmigoJack, Thanks for the suggestion. My issue is resolved now. Below is the approach that I have used. I have used 'exports' to export the functions from Delphi unit so that it is accessible from the C code. Also I have created a single shared library(.so) from all the object files(.o) and used that 'so' file in the Delphi code instead of linking multiple '.o' file or '.a' file using $LINK.